How do I get an output if two objects collide in Rec Room?
I’m making a game mode where, if a basket collides with one of many eggs, the egg disappears, and a counter goes up. Can anyone help?

Pivot the basket to a trigger volume that only detects objects with tag "egg". Add this tag to all eggs. When it detects an object, set it's position to 0,0,-1000.
